# How to reload CSS after ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, css, ajax, django

I am trying to fix the CSS formatting on my page Actually i am using Django endless pagination
to load my content on page scroll but when new content is loaded the CSS applied to the page is not working or has to be refreshed .....So please tell me how to apply CSS to the new content loaded by the ajax call ..

index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fashion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="product_container">
    <ul class="product_list">
        <div class="endless_page_template">
            {% include page_template %}
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
{% block js %}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="static/js/endless_on_scroll.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>    
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true,
    endless_on_scroll_margin : 10,
    paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 5        
});</script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```
.product_list
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.product_list li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:150px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.product_container
{
    width:800px;
    column-gap: 0;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

index_page.html :

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate 10 contextList %}
{% for item in contextList %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.productURL }}" ><img src="/images/{{ item.image_paths.0 }}/" height="100" width="100" border='1px solid'/></a>
        <br>
        <span class="price">
        <span class="mrp">MRP : {{ item.productMRP}}</span>
        {% if item.productPrice %}<br>
        <span class="discounted_price">Offer Price : {{ item.productPrice}}</span>
        {%endif%}
        </span>
    </li>  
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% show_more "even more" "working" %}
```

I have applied CSS to disable `ul` bullets but after ajax call new data has bullets it means for new data CSS is not working ....Can anyone help me

Comment: Can you post the resulting html page with some sample ul that has been loaded and isn't being styled? My hunch is that the selector you're using isn't correct.

Comment: css rules are static, any items added to the dom after the page loads should be subject to the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following css:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

If that works, then your css selector `.product_list` is just incorrect and you'll need to specify it in a way that catches all of the li's.

Comment: I can if you post the html of the actual page, not the templates.

Comment: This all of it there is no other page

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is generated and served to the browser when you are actual viewing this page in a browser.

Comment: Thanks man for your help but it was my fault i forgot to remove `</ul>` after `{% endfor %}` in `index_page.html` after removing it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found only solution to put CSS styles inline in loaded tags.

This is not best practice, but worked for me.